# Linking Error: Boost Library on Windows using MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, linker, mingw

I'm using Windows 7 64x and have MinGW installed.

My goal is to use boost libraries on Eclipse (here: `boost_program_options`).

The boost libraries are correctly installed and I can see the file `libboost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_53.lib` under `C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib`

I now attempt to link this in Eclipse by going to `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries`:

Here I enter for `Library Search Path` (`-L`): `C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib`
and for `Libraries` (`-l`): `boost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_53`

When trying to build, I get the following error message:

```
11:06:54 **** Build of configuration Debug for project AP ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/HW1EX1.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0" -I"C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\boost\program_options" -I"C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\boost" -I"C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\boost\program_options\detail" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HW1EX1.d" -MT"src/HW1EX1.d" -o "src/HW1EX1.o" "../src/HW1EX1.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/HW1EX1.cpp

Building target: AP.exe
Invoking: MinGW C++ Linker
g++ -LC:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib -static-libgcc -o "AP.exe"  ./src/HW1EX1.o   -lboost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_53
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_53
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [AP.exe] Error 1

11:06:57 Build Finished (took 3s.80ms)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have downloaded the binary distribution which is compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler (the `...-vc90-...` is a hint). Or maybe you've built it yourself, but you did it with Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler. You have to build Boost from source with your MinGW, as you cannot mix C++ code produced by different C++ compilers. In other words, in your situation you cannot link to the library produced by Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler using MinGW.

In addition, I suspect that `-LC:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib` is not going to work because there are backward slashes and it is not quoted. So it should be either `-L"C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib"` or `-LC:/MinGW/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib`. I'd prefer the second variant, so try to change backward slashes to forward ones and see how it goes. Also double check that `libboost_program_options-mgw46-1_53.a` is really in the `C:\MinGW\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have replaced     boost_program_options-vc90-mt-gd-1_53 with     boost_program_options-mgw46-1_53 but I still get the same error message. Anyone have any other ideas?